# jQuery: Only show one item, when item is appended to List

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have a button that appends items to list,
When an item is selected, all other items are hidden, and only the selected item is shown.

Objective:
What I want is to have only the "last" appended item to show.
Currently, all the recently appended items are shown in the list.

jQuery appending items to the List:

```
//AppendImagePreview
$(function() {
    var itemCount = 1;
$("#addImageButton").click(function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault();
    var itemCount = ($("[id^='item-']").length + 1);

var elementPreview = $("<li id='item-" + itemCount + "'></li>");

 $("#cardList").append(elementCard);
  $("#previewList").append(elementPreview);
    });
});
```

jQuery that hides all content, except the selected item:

```
var lastSelectedCardDataType;
var lastSelectedPreviewItemId;
var lastSelectedCardId;
var onClickCard = function(dst){    
    var t = dst.id;
    console.log('dst.id=' + dst.id);
    console.log('t=' + t); //(t = item-2)

    $('.previews').hide(); //hide ok

    var q = '#prw-' + t; //change to class (q = prw-item-2)
    console.log('t=' + t);
    console.log('q=' + q); //not showing

    lastSelectedCardDataType = $(dst).attr("data-type");
    lastSelectedPreviewItemId = q;
    lastSelectedCardId = "#"+ t;

    console.log("lastSelectedPreviewItemId"+lastSelectedPreviewItemId);
    console.log("lastSelectedCardId"+lastSelectedCardId);

    $(q).show();
};
```

List append Location:

```
<ul id="previewList" class="previewList">
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your last appended item into global variable

```
var lastAppendedId;
$(function() {
    var itemCount = 1;
    $("#addImageButton").click(function(e) {  
        e.preventDefault();
        var itemCount = ($("[id^='item-']").length + 1);

        var elementPreview = $("<li id='item-" + itemCount + "' class ='listItem'></li>");
        lastAppendedId = elementPreview.attr('id');
        $("#cardList").append(elementCard);
        $("#previewList").append(elementPreview);
    });
});
```

then Onclick you may want to iterate over listItems and hide all except the lastAppended Item

```
$('.listItem').each(function() {
  var currentId = this.id;
  if(currentId !== lastAppendedId) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
);
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/sir4ju1/3NrgX/